# Stemming in other languages through the API

Tags: eventbrite

Does the Eventbrite SE stem words in languages other than English? If so, what languages are they and how is the language determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick check using the interactive docs here:
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/

Spanish-language stemming seems to work in many cases - since many Spanish words are pluralized by adding an "s" to the end. A search for "gato" and "gatos" both return the same result list.

From what I understand, SOLR's basic stemming support will automatically try removing or adding the letter 's' to the end of most search keywords.  I think it does the same for other common english-language word extensions, like 'ing'.

Eventbrite is putting a lot of focus on i18n, and support for international events.

I would try testing several words from the languages that you would like to support.  If you find the support for stemming in a particular language to be lacking, please pass your feedback on to the Eventbrite support team.